# How can I use an "if" to generate part of a shell pipeline?

Tags: bash

I have code like the following:

```
if foo; then
  bar |
else
  baz |
fi
qux
```

...intended to evaluate to either `bar | qux` or `baz | qux`, depending on whether `foo` is true.

More specifically:

```
if [ -f path/file.txt ]
then
    find "/home/repo/sources" -type f '(' -name '*.upl' -o -name '*.int' -o -name '*.ini' -o -name '*.txt' -o -name '*.htm' -o -name '*.inc' -o -name '*.css' -o -name '*.example' -o -name '*.cfg' -o -name '*.cache' -o -name '*.manifest' -o -name '*.dsp' -o -name '*.vdf' -o -name '*.lst' -o -name '*.gam' -o -name '*.scr' -o -name '*.nut' -o -name '*.db' -o -name '*.inf' -o -name '*.rc' -o -name '*.bsp' -o -name '*.nav' ')' -printf '%P\0' |
else
    find "/home/repo/sources" -type f '(' -name '*.upl' -o -name '*.int' -o -name '*.ini' -o -name '*.txt' -o -name '*.htm' -o -name '*.inc' -o -name '*.css' -o -name '*.example' -o -name '*.cfg' -o -name '*.cache' -o -name '*.manifest' -o -name '*.dsp' -o -name '*.vdf' -o -name '*.lst' -o -name '*.gam' -o -name '*.scr' -o -name '*.nut' -o -name '*.db' -o -name '*.inf' -o -name '*.rc' -o -name '*.nav' ')' -printf '%P\0' |
fi
```

My error:

```
/home/repo/sources/test.sh: line 2207: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
/home/repo/sources/test.sh: line 2207: `else'
```

If i remove the all the if statment and just put one of the find's it will work without any errors. After the find outside the If statment I have this:     `while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do`

Comment: BTW, I'd consider putting the specific options you want in one branch but not the other in an array. Much easier to only have *one* `find` command, but with some of its arguments being optional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd strongly suggest writing this to only run `find` once, and branch in setting up your array. For example:

```
# set up a simple array with all the names common to both lists
types=( cache cfg css db dsp example gam htm inc inf ini int lst manifest
        nav nut rc scr txt upl vdf )

# branch *here*, deciding whether to append an extra type to the list
[ -f path/file.txt ] && types+=( bsp )

# convert our list, whatever it contains, to a list of arguments to find
findArgs=( -false )
for type in "${types[@]}"; do
  findArgs+=( -o -name "*.$type" )
done

# expand that list
find . '(' "${findArgs[@]}" ')' -printf '%P\0'
```

This is in accordance with section 1.5 of [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050#I.27m_constructing_a_command_based_on_information_that_is_only_known_at_run_time).

Comment: Might be clearer to initialize `findArgs=( -false )`, then append `-o -name "*.$type"` for each type.

Answer (score 0):

Charles Duffy's answer provides a better way to do this that avoids the whole issue, but just for the record I'd like to answer how to make part of a pipeline conditional. The short answer is that you can't interleave shell syntaxes, like having part of a pipeline inside an `if` statement and another part outside. You can have a pipeline inside an `if`, or an `if` inside one stage of a pipeline (or even an `if` inside a pipeline inside an `if` inside...), but they have to *nest*, one inside the other.

In this case, the nesting is easy to achieve: put the `if` fully inside a stage of the pipeline, by simply moving the `|` after `then`:

```
if foo; then
  bar
else
  baz
fi |
qux
```